# Rest API List item count code works on SP 2013 not SPO

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-online

The code below used to count number of items in a list works on SP2013. But when copied to SPO, it fails.

Kindly review the code below and advice.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$(function(){
var requestUri = "<<SITE URL>>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('XYZ')/Items";
$.ajax({
url: requestUri,
type: "GET",
headers: {
"accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
"content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"X-RequestDigest":$("#_REQUESTDIGEST").val()
},
success: onSuccess,
});

function onSuccess(data) {
var itemsCount = data.d.results.length;
document.getElementById("ABC").value = (itemsCount);}

});
});
</script>
DDA Count: <input type="text" id="ABC" value="">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before posting a question. In general, the SO community isn't a "code-review-service". In particular, your question isn't specific and you simply state that it fails but not how (What's the error message? How does it fail?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please modify the code as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    var requestUri = "https://zheguo.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList9')/Items";
    $.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
    "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest":$("#_REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data.d.results);
        var itemsCount = data.d.results.length;
        document.getElementById("ABC").value = itemsCount;
    }, 
    error: function(error)
     {  
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  

      }  
    });

});
</script>
```

[image]

[image]